# Auto Commit In JDBC (Java)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I just tried JDBC and figured out that auto-commit is enable in java but not in SQL-Command line it means that if I execute a 3 queries (say), and second one is wrong syntax wise the first once executes and flow of program breaks after that how to clean the first memory out of the local buffer in that case?

Comment: You can disable auto commit - `connection.setAutoCommit (false);`

Comment: @Eran Not what i asked, I asked how to clear the buffer not how to disable auto commit please read the question.

Comment: @SaubhagyaSrivastava: what "buffer" are you talking about? And which DBMS are you using? And what is the "error" you get? And what are the statements you run? **[Edit]** your question  and provide that information - do **NOT** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use any of below depending on your requirements :

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false); // set False to disable auto-commit

conn.rollback( ); // to Rollback previous transaction
```

You can also refer **[Using Transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)**

Comment: If my second query is wrong but i still have connection.rollback(); will it still clear the local buffer?

Comment: @SaubhagyaSrivastava What is this "local buffer" you are talking about; there is no such thing.